# Twitter URL is not loading at webview in my android applications

Tags: android, twitter

i'm using twitter api in my android application In this when i login into twitter first time only my twitter url loading in the webview when i try to share image second time the url is not loading webview shows as blank.

```
private void setUpWebView(String murl) {
    mWebView = new WebView(getContext());
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new TwitterWebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    System.out.println("Url is ---->" + murl);
    mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mWebView.loadUrl(murl);
    mWebView.requestFocus();
    System.out.println("URL Finished");
    mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);
    mContent.addView(mWebView);
}
```

in the above the murl i can get  different access token to share the image at second time but that url is not loading in the the web view what mistake i did.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Twitter does not load in WebView if some settings is activated. Got the same problem myself when makeing my WebView twitter app.

I can not tell you why it does like this, but only that it is most likely one of your settings.

Edit: 
This code works for me:

```
 web.setWebViewClient(webView);  
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
    web.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);


        web.loadUrl("http://www.twitter.com");
```

Comment: thx for ur reply and Before using the domstorage setting it was run like the above